# Node.js fs.readFile store read data in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a node.js app which will process a lot of numerical data.
How do I store in memory data which has been read by fs.readFile, Example:

```
var somedata = ''; 
fs.readFile('somefile', 'utf8', function(err,data){
 somedata = data; 
});

//fs.readFile is done by now.. 
console.log(somedata) // undefined, why is this not in memory?
```

I read file data periodically and currently I have to write what ive read elsewhere and read it again to use it in another function.

How do i just store it in memory? Is this just how javascript works??

Comment: Note: i know readFile returns a promise.. Even if there is a timeout the data read still is not saved to the variable.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Since you're using node, the short answer is to use readFileSync instead.

Comment: @ChrisG yea too bad all the other libraries out there dont have sync versions of their async methods...

Comment: That's why JS got Promises and `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `readFile()` the function

```
function(err,data){
 somedata = data; 
}
```

gets executed at a later time (asynchronously), which is common JavaScript programming pattern.

JS in a browser and NodeJS is single-thread and uses [event-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for concurrency.

Using `readFileSync()` will stop execution and return the result of read operation (like you would expect with other languages).

```
var somedata = ''; 
somedata = fs.readFileSync('somefile', 'utf8');

//fs.readFileSync is done by now.. (which is important difference with readFile()
console.log(somedata)
```

References:

- [readFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)
- [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)
- [Understanding Async Programming in Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)